# Pandas data frame with repeating sequences: How to do a spaghetti plot?

Tags: python, pandas, plot, time-series

I've got the data looking like the following data as `pandas.DataFrame`:

```
                                  diff_1       diff_2
1949-01-01 06:00:00               -0.555       -0.123
1949-01-01 07:00:00               -0.654        0.230
1949-01-02 06:00:00               -0.879        0.012
1949-01-02 07:00:00               -0.459        0.672
1949-01-03 06:00:00               -0.588        0.980
1949-01-03 07:00:00               -0.068        0.375
1950-01-01 06:00:00               -0.654        0.572
1950-01-01 07:00:00               -0.544        0.092
1950-01-02 06:00:00                0.374       -0.275
1950-01-02 07:00:00                0.562       -0.260
1950-01-03 06:00:00               -0.200        0.240
1950-01-03 07:00:00               -0.226        0.202
```

Now, I want to do a "spaghetti plot", where the "spaghetti groups" in one color are determinated whether the curve is diff_1 or diff_2 (so x-axis is the time from 01-01 to 01-03, y-axis are the differences, each "spaghetti" is one year).
I tried to orient at this question:

[Plot pandas data frame with year over year data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30379789/plot-pandas-data-frame-with-year-over-year-data)

However, I fear I have got one dimension too many. Any ideas how this could work?

EDIT: The following simple image illustrates what I'm looking for. The multiple lines for one color result from the fact that the time period on the x-axis repeat annually.

[image]

Comment: Could you give an example of what you are trying to acomplish? Maybe draw something in paint if it is about plotting or an example dataframe if you are trying to transform your dataframe into something easily plottable.

Comment: It is about both. The result should look like the plot in the linked question, just that in my case "diff_1"/"diff_2" appears in the legend  and there is more than one graph in one color (representing the years).
I've added a very simple graphics that illustrates what I desire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the best I could do, I am not totally satisfied but it might be good enough:

```
# add a column with the year so you can pivot on it later.
tdf = df.assign(year=df.index.year)
# make all dates have the same year (a leap one just in case)
tdf.index = df.index.map(lambda x: x.replace(year=2004))
# pivot using years as columns and put them in the topmost level.
tdf = (tdf.pivot(columns='year').swaplevel(0, 1, axis='columns'))
print(tdf)

year                  1949   1950   1949   1950
                    diff_1 diff_1 diff_2 diff_2
2004-01-01 06:00:00 -0.555 -0.654 -0.123  0.572
2004-01-01 07:00:00 -0.654 -0.544  0.230  0.092
2004-01-02 06:00:00 -0.879  0.374  0.012 -0.275
2004-01-02 07:00:00 -0.459  0.562  0.672 -0.260
2004-01-03 06:00:00 -0.588 -0.200  0.980  0.240
2004-01-03 07:00:00 -0.068 -0.226  0.375  0.202

# create a list of as many colors as columns in df
color = [c['color'] for c in plt.rcParams['axes.prop_cycle'][:df.columns.size]]
# plot
ax = plt.subplot()
for year in tdf.columns.levels[0]:
    tdf[year].plot(color=color, legend=False, ax=ax)
plt.legend(ax.lines[:df.columns.size], df.columns, loc='best')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Now customize the tick labels to your heart content.

Comment: Okay, indeed, it seems to be a major undertaking, but obviously it works! :-)